# Shopify : If checkbox is checked, add to cart

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, shopify, checked

I am currently having trouble appraoching a simple code to create functionality for a checkbox.
I'd like for the following :
When checkbox is checked (on product page), add the item to the cart immediately.

Would anyone know the right way to approach this?

Nick

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Check how to create How to [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example so that you can get a much better response to your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with onchange event in the checkbox and with in it, you need to place a ajax request.

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm not super familair with js / jquery. Would you know a way  to start this? Here's the ajax for shopify https://help.shopify.com/themes/development/getting-started/using-ajax-api